# python_qpid_proton for mac using amqps

Tags: python, amqp, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to install python_qpid_proton on Mac OS X El Capitan and I'm having trouble getting it to find the SSL libraries when I actually make a connection.

When trying to use the library, I get this error attempting to connect using amqps:

```
proton.SSLUnavailable: amqps: SSL libraries not found
```

I've installed OpenSSL using the latest version of homebrew and have this in my .bashrc file:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I've also tried rebuilding python_qpid_proton using both pip and the setup.py file and also examined the output from the setup.py install run to see if there was any sort of warning or error and did not see any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Here's how I fixed it on my Mac OS Sierra. I guess you run into the same issue with El Capitan. By running the install in verbose mode I recognised missing dependencies. The following actions fixed it on my end:

Uninstall python-qpid-proton:

```
pip uninstall python-qpid-proton
```

Install missing dependencies (swig + pkg-config) via brew:

```
brew install swig
brew install pkg-config
```

Install python-qpid-proton and pip disable cache to force rebuild of lib:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"; pip install python-qpid-proton --verbose --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: Any chance you came across, and worked past this error?

`ImportError: dlopen(/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/_cproton.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _CRYPTO_num_locks`

Comment: not working...
proton._exceptions.SSLUnavailable: amqps: SSL libraries not found

Comment: the same happens for me to following this solution: `proton._exceptions.SSLUnavailable: amqps: SSL libraries not found`

Answer (score 2):

In my case the solution was the following

```
pip uninstall python-qpid-proton
```

then install required

```
brew install swig
brew install pkg-config
```

and the setup flags:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"
```

and finally compile as stated before:

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"; pip install python-qpid-proton --verbose --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: I had to also install libssl on top of this which was missing on my VM (see this thread http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/Proton-bindings-for-python3-td7666703.html) , but these config settings worked